# How can i flatten rails i18n files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

Rails I18n is great for translations, as a programmer.

But some clients prefer to have their say in the i18n files we are making for them so we would like to send a "flattened" version via Excel for them to complete.

For example, instead of sending

```
en: 
  sessions:
    new:
      login: "Ingresa"
      signup: "Regístrate"
```

We would like to have it

```
en.sessions.new.login  "Ingresa"
en.sessions.new.signup "Regístrate"
```

Which is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extended version can be checked here: https://repl.it/Dg4U/0

When you ask for a translation I18n gives you the content, or a Hash.

So your beginning Hash can be

```
I18n.t('.') # The root element
```

Then you can apply this code

```
results = []

def squash(previous_key = '', h)
  h.each do |key,value|
    this_key = "#{previous_key}.#{key.to_s}"
    if value.is_a? Hash
      squash(this_key, value) 
    elsif value.is_a? Array
      results << "#{this_key}: #{value.inspect}"
    else
      results << "#{this_key}: #{value}"
    end
  end 
end

squash 'en', I18n.t('.')
```

There you can user the results array as you please to use it.
I just printed it on screen and pasted it in Excel.